# Visual Basic not fetching from database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using Visual Basic and Telerik Reporting. I have Startup screen (Form0).

When I click one buton on Startup Scren (Form 0)  it opens other Form - Form1 . In this Form1 I do my calculations. When I click on button that is in this Form1 it save's data to database and open's Form2 that contains ReportViewer and ComboBox in PARAMETER AREA.

That ComoBox is filled with sql command - > selecting all data (from one column of my database). But it don't fill's that ComboBox with data that I just entered and saved in database.

It only fill's it correctly when I restart my program.

```
  Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        Dim nova_ponuda As New NovaPonuda
        nova_ponuda.ShowDialog() /// OPENS FORM1

    End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

        Dim print_ponude As New PrintPonude
        print_ponude.Show()        /// OPENS FORM 2 - one with ReportViewer

    End Sub
```

ReportViewer uses Report1 that fetch data from two SqlDataSources. First connection string form which ComboBox is filled:

```
  SELECT * FROM aktivne_ponude
```

Second SqlDataSource connection string:

```
  SET @SQLString = N'SELECT * FROM ' + 
QUOTENAME(@table_name)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

// It Selects all data from table which name is defined by selection in ComboBox

Comment: Post your code for `Form0`, `Form1` and `Form2`.

Comment: Thank you Karl for response. It's approximately sum of 800 lines of code. I must extract most important parts.

Comment: Is your code using any type of cached `DataSet` or something like that?

Comment: Hm...very interesting...I have one DataSet but it's not used..maybe something is fishy there. Thanks Karl.

Comment: I deletet DataSet completely..that's not problem :(

Comment: I know you update the database with this data, but do you ever requery the database and reset the Combos datasource to be that of the 'New' data?

Comment: I am noob..not so expirienced in programing..currently building solution for some calculation I do for some project. Thank you that is very helpful reminder.

Comment: And where do you bind the result of the `SELECT` from the database to the `ComboBox`?

Comment: In Telerik ReportViewer ... ReportParameter(s)